# How to validate input text to ensure only floats or ints greater than a minimum value are entered?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input tag of type text.

The user is supposed to enter a float or int, greater than 4.
How to I verify that the user has not entered any non-numeric characters ?
Decimal points are ok:

For example:

1. 10.1 (ok)
2. 10 (ok)
3. 10$ (not ok)
4. abcs (not ok)
5. .0.12 (not ok -> Too many periods)
6. 4 (not ok -> number must be greater than 4)
7. 1a (not ok)

How do I do this? Parsing each and every character in the text box seems clumsy, and I'm don't know think I can do this with a regex. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You should take a look at jquery-inputmask: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

Comment: almost what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299330/javascript-regex-validating-a-double-float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and *carefully* read through how to use it.  Until ECMA 6 is widely used, `isNaN()` is probably the best in conjunction with [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseFloat()`:

Here's a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/HbqF3/3/